# Solving $e^x + x = 5$ for $x$ without using a numerical method?

Tags: exponentiation

Canadian economist Mike Moffat [asks on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/MikePMoffatt/status/98835752636526593):

> Math nerd Q: Is there a way to solve $e^x + x = 5$ for $x$, without using a numerical method?

Comment: So, based on the answers given, "NO".

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by 'numerical method'. Sure, you need to use a numerical method to compute the W function (Newton's method works well). But you need to use a numerical method to compute values of the exponential function, sine function or even the square root function, and this isn't really so different.

Comment: If you want a closed form expression for the solution in terms of elementary functions, then the answer is *no*.

Comment: @Chris Taylor: Hurrah for the comment about needing a numerical method for exponential, sine, square root. There are a number of questions on this site for which this should be part of the answer.

Comment: @lhf: technically, you are incorrect.  Every constant function is elementary, and some constant function has this value...  However, the function $x = g(y)$ solving $e^x+x=y$ is, indeed, non-elementary.

Comment: @GEdgar, you're right, that's what I meant. It *may* happen that the solution for $y=5$ has an elementary form, though I doubt it, 5 not looking special in any way.

Comment: @Chris: Yes! YES! That's *precisely* what annoys me about people who say "I don't want to use a numerical method"; even using the humble square root function of your computing environment is a bleeding numerical method! You said it, dude!

Answer (score 6):

Write $y=5-x$. Then $ye^y=e^5$. Using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), this gives $x=5-W(e^5)$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, write it as $e^x =(5-x)$, then $e^5 e^{x-5} = (5-x)$ then $e^5 =(5-x)e^{5-x}$. Denote $y=5-x$. Equation becomes $e^5 = y*e^y$ which is an implicit equation defining Lambert W function. The $ y = W(e^5)$ and $x = 5- W(e^5)$.

$W(e^5)$ is approximately $3.69$ hence $x = 1.31$, see [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5-%20W%28e%5E5%29)

Answer (score 1):

Write $y = 5-x$, giving

$$e^{5-y} = y$$

and hence

$$y e^y = e^5$$

This can be inverted using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to give

$$y = W(e^5)$$

and hence

$$x = 5 - W(e^5)$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation and take the natural log:

$
e^x=5-x
$. Then
$
x=ln(5-x)
$.
Or
$
x=ln(5)+ln(1-\frac{x}{5})
$.
Linearizing the second RHS term gives:
$
ln(1-\frac{x}{5})\approx-\frac{x}{5}+O(x^2)
$.
Hence an approximate answer for x is obtained by:
$
x\approx ln(5)-\frac{x}{5}
$,
yielding:
$
x\approx\frac{5}{6}\cdot ln(5)=1.34
$.
Compared to the answer obtained by the Lambert W-function this answer is about 2% off.

Comment: OP asks for non numerical solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Lambert function or any numerical method, you can have explicit *approximations* using Newton-like methods of high order $n$ starting at $x=1$.

For example
$$x_{(2)}=\frac{5}{1+e}$$
$$x_{(3)}=\frac{10+14 e-e^2}{2+8 e+e^2}$$
$$x_{(4)}=\frac{60+296 e+32 e^2-4 e^3}{12+116 e+56 e^2+2 e^3}$$
$$x_{(5)}=\frac{720+8016 e+4344 e^2-120 e^3-18 e^4}{144+2592 e+3048 e^2+456 e^3+6 e^4}$$
$$x_{(6)}=\frac{14400+286464 e+381696 e^2+45504 e^3-4224 e^4-96 e^5}{2880+81984 e+189696
   e^2+69984 e^3+4416 e^4+24 e^5}$$ I stop here because the formulae start to be too large for the page.

Converted to decimals, the above *approximations* are
$$\{1.3447071,1.3061341,1.3064721,1.3065586,1.3065589\}$$

Answer (score -2):

Step 1. Transform the equation $e^x+x=5$ into $e^x=5-x$

Step 2. Write each side of the new equation as function : $y_1=e^x$ and $y_2=5-x$

Step 3. Graph these two functions in Desmos Graphing Calculator (you find its application in internet)

Step 4. Find the intersection of the two graphs. It has an $x$ and $y$ value.

Step.5 The $x$-value is the solution of our equation : $x=1.307$ (approximately)