# Solution to $a\cdot e^{bx} - cx = d$

Tags: exponentiation

Similar to the question asked here: [Solving $e^x + x = 5$ for $x$ without using a numerical method?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55414/solving-ex-x-5-for-x-without-using-a-numerical-method)

How can I get a solution for $a\cdot e^{bx} - cx = d$, where a, b, c, d are constants? Is there a way I can get it in terms of the Lambert W function?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 5):

Write $y=(b/c)(cx+d)$ to get $(b/c) \cdot a e^{bx}= y$. Note $bx=y-bd/c$, so this is $(ab/c)e^{y-bd/c}=y$, and then multiply by $-e^{-y}$ to get $-(ab/c) e^{-bd/c} = -ye^{-y}$. This means $-y=W(-\frac{ab}{c} e^{-bd/c})$, so

$$x=-\frac{d}{c}-\frac{1}{b}W\left(-\frac{ab}{c}e^{-bd/c}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to assume $a = 1$. One solution is
\begin{align}
x = - \frac{bd + c \ W(-\frac{ab}{c}e^{-bd/c})}{bc},
\end{align}
where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function. This can be proved using the functional identity $W(z) e^{W(z)} = z$.

Answer (score 0):

You may assume $a=1$. Then Wolfram Alpha gives you the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5E%28b+x%29+-+c+x+%3D+d)  in terms of the Lambert $W$ function.