# Solving $y=P_1+P_2x+P_3e^{P_4x}$.

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I having trouble with this function:

$y=P_1+P_2x+P_3e^{P_4x}$

I would like to solve it in terms of x. This means I know $y, P_1, P_2, P_3$ and $P_4$ and I want to calculate $x$ by varying $y$ ($y$ is always positive in my system).
I found another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55414/solving-ex-x-5-for-x-without-using-a-numerical-method), which is similar to my problem.

But I did not well understand how the Lambert $W$ function (assuming my function will requires this function) can be computed.

Answer (score 1):

Most computer algebra systems compute the $W$ function (defined by $x = W(x) e^{W(x)}$), it's Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) gives details on it's computation, and more detailed references.

No, there is no easy way out. Unfortunately. At least you can use a standard function in your solution, one that is well-known.

The GNU Scientific Library [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl) includes a function that computes $W(x)$. It should be available on any Linux system, and probably as an add-on on MacOS and Windows.